# How to I review an application to choose the right indexes - php & mysql

Tags: php, database, orm, indexing

We have an existing PHP/MySQL app which doesn't have indexes configured correctly (monitoring shows that we do 85% table scans, ouch!)

What is a good process to follow to identify where we should be putting our indexes?

We're using PHP (Kohana using ORM for the DB access), and MySQL.

Comment: Start by looking at the slow queries.

Comment: Add indexes on all columns that are in your joins and on the right side of every `WHERE`

Comment: We don't have enough data to generate slow queries, we're not in production yet. And using ORM hides the SQL from easy access. In past projects I've always written the SQL myself so it was easy to index as we went.

Comment: You should be able to get all database queries from the profiler: [kohana framework - profiler](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/profiling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer likely depends on many things. For example, your strategy might be different if you want to optimize SELECTs at all costs or whether INSERTs are important to you as well. You might do well to read a MySQL Performance Tuning book or web site. There are several decent-to-great ones.

If you have a Slow Query Log, check it to see if there are particular queries that are causing problems.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html

If you know the types of queries you'll be running or have identified problematic queries via the Slow Query Log or other mechanisms, you can then use the EXPLAIN command to get some stats on those queries. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html

Once you have the output from EXPLAIN, you can use it to optimize.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are not just for the primary keys or the unique keys. If there are any columns in your table that you will search by, you should almost always index them.

I think this will help you on your database problems.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/